# How to loop multi dimensional array to get values

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this multi-dimensional array and I'm trying to convert it into array given below

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )
    [team_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 654868479
            [1] => 463733228
        )
    [seed] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
)
```

I want following result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [team_id] => 654868479
            [seed] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [team_id] => 463733228
            [seed] => 3
        )
)
```

Here is what I have achieved so far. I actually want `$seeded[]` array is the same format as it is required to submit `update_batch`. Which will ultimately update database records.

```
$seeds = $this->input->post();
$i=0;
foreach ($seeds as $key => $value){
    if(!empty($key) && !empty($value)){
        for($i=0; $i=5; $i++) {
            $seeded[] = array(
                'id' => (id go here),
                'tournament_id' => $tournament_id,
                'stage_id' => $stage_id,
                'seed_id' => (seed go here),
                'team_name' => (team_id go here),
            );
        }
        $this->db->update_batch('tournament_seed', $seeded, 'id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the array and convert it using below code.

```
$seeded= array();
for($i =0; $i < count($seeds['id']); $i++){
    $tempArr['id'] = $seeds['id'][$i];
    $tempArr['team_id'] = $seeds['team_id'][$i];
    $tempArr['seed'] = $seeds['seed'][$i];
    $seeded[] = $tempArr;
}
```

Comment: Please quote your indexes, they will be read as PHP constants (in future versions of PHP), which will be undefined.

Comment: Undefined variable: arr

Comment: Assign old array to $arr or use your old array name

Answer (score 0):

I've written a function that will allow you to transform any array of similar structure to what you have above, to an array of the form you are looking for.

You can build your array in this way:

```php
$arr = [
    'id'      => [1, 3],
    'team_id' => [654868479, 463733228],
    'seed'    => [1, 2],
];

function array_flatten($arr) {
    $res = [];
    foreach($arr as $id => $valuesArray) {
        foreach($valuesArray as $index => $value)
            $res[$index][$id] = $value;
    }
    return $res;
}

print_r(array_flatten($arr));
```

Hope this helps,